# tfs2010 same label different branches

Tags: visual-studio-2010, label, source-control-explorer

Given this structure:

```
$/TeamProject/
  Project A/
    Development [Branch] <-- Labeled "v1.0" @ latest
  Project B/
    Development [Branch] <-- new pending v1.0 release
```

Product A already has a label "v1.0" set on its Development Branch.
But now when I try to label Product B branch with label "v1.0", VS is saying that that label already exists and will be overwritten?

How can this be when the Project A label was set on the Project A branch and has nothing to do with the Project B branches.

Product A and Product B are part of the same system but are released independently as and when they are updated.

Is this a bug or am I missing some step to the process.

I am using the VS Team SCE as I prefer to use a GUI than CLI.

I have read somewhere that a label has scope, surely when you set a label on a folder in VS it sets *that* folder as the scope, no?

Thanks,
Gary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439(v=vs.80).aspx (the vs2010 one does not mention this but it still applies):

> Labels created within the graphical user interface are scoped to the root folder of the team project within which they are created. Labels created from the command line are scoped to the longest common path shared by the items specified in the label command.

Not sure why MS have chosen to do this, as you can right-click a branch / folder and select "Apply Label" which is kind of misleading.